# Checking for duplicates before inserting EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

In my .NET Core application, I am checking for duplicates before adding a list of objects to my database,  like so (names changed for sensitivity reasons):

```
public void Add(List<MyClass> myClass)
{
     var nonDuplicatedList = new List<MyClass>();

     for (int i = 0; i < myClass.Count; i++)
     {
         if(!dbContext.Table.Any(x => my filter here to avoid duplicates based on keys))
             nonDuplicatedList.Add(myClass[i]);
     }

     dbContext.Table.AddRange(nonDuplicatedList);
     dbContext.SaveChanges()
}
```

my class:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public string IdName {get;set;}
    public DateTime Datehour {get;set;}
    public decimal? Ratio1 {get;set;}
    public decimal? Ratio2 {get;set;}
    public decimal? Ratio3 {get;set;}
    public int? Total {get;set;}
}
```

Since I'm looping "myClass" and checking if the entry is already in the database, is this very costly? Does EF Core check one by one or does it understand to make a single query out of the loop to check for multiple records at the same time?

A duplicate is decided by a combination of the properties so I'm not sure how to go on about it other than looping trough my list and checking it against the database.

Comment: Can you show `MyClass`?

Comment: Are you aware that this could still introduce duplicates? If `myClass` already contains a dupe in itself, it will be inserted.

Comment: @vernou Added class to example

Comment: @Fildor Yes, MyClass has been filtered allready before it reaches Add method so we can assume it is unique

Comment: How is defined the keys? Fluent declaration? In this case, can you show the fluent declaration of the entity?

Comment: @vernou maybe "keys" was missleading, a duplicate is decided by a combination of the properties.

Comment: *duplicate is decided by a combination of the properties* you have to make a composite key in your database and the database will preserve the identity and integrity, don't depend on your code checking !

Comment: To delcare the key, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys). If it's database first, also you need to define the constraint in your database.

Comment: @IbramReda I do have a composite key, the insert is run by a job and when it throws by duplicate the job fails. We had issues with data being removed/delayed and that caused the duplicate inserts to happen (i.e running the same data twice), thats why I wish to filter before I add.